# How to prove $((2^n)^{1/3} < c \cdot 2^n)$ for some $c, n_0 > 0$ and for all $n \geq n_0$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $((2^n)^{1/3} < c \cdot 2^n)$ for all $c, n_0 > 0$ and some $n \geq n_0$. However, I'm not sure how to start.

Part of the solution says,

Let $c > 0$ and $n_0$ be arbitrary. We need to find an $n \geq n_0$ such that $(2^{n/3} < c \cdot 2^n)$. I don't know what to set $n$ to.

Comment: As stated, the problem is trivial. My guess is that the problem that you are really interested in is this: given $c>0$, prove that there is some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant n_0\implies\sqrt[3]{2^n}<c2^n$.

Comment: Yes, how would you prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Take $c>0$. Then\begin{align}\sqrt[3]{2^n}<c2^n&\iff2^n<c^32^{3n}\\&\iff\frac1{c^3}<2^{2n}\\&\iff c^{-3}<4^n\\&\iff\log(c^{-3})<\log(4^n)\\&\iff -3\log(c)<n\log(4).\end{align}So, take $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $n_0>-\frac{3\log c}{\log 4}$. Then,$$n\geqslant n_0\implies n>-\frac{3\log c}{\log 4}\iff\sqrt[3]{2^n}<c2^n.$$

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your comment. I think the question is asking to find an n such that $n \geq n_0 \rightarrow 2^{n/3}< c2^n$

Comment: No. The question is about find a $n_0$ such that $n\geqslant n_0\implies\sqrt[3]{2^n}<c2^n$.